# showing x-axis values at particular point clearly using matplotlin in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am ploting two graph in one graph using following code. And also i want see X-axis values on some point in graph itself. Because i am ploting two graph in one plot, so i am two values for one point. I want to see both values clearly. But when values are closer they collide each and values are not visible clearly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)
plt.style.use(['default'])
a=[1.23,2.24,3.12,1.11,2.46]
b=[1.24,2.23,3.15,1.25,2.78]
xc=range(5)
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
for x,y in zip(xc,a):
    plt.text(x, y, '%.2f' % y, ha='center', va= 'bottom')
for x,y in zip(xc,b):
    plt.text(x, y, '%.2f' % y, ha='center', va= 'bottom')
plt.plot(xc,a)
plt.plot(xc,b)
plt.xlabel('num of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.title('train_loss vs val_loss')
plt.legend(['train','val'])
```

Please help me to code for better visualization of graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `plt.text()` configurations.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)
plt.style.use(['default'])
a=[1.23,2.24,3.12,1.11,2.46]
b=[1.24,2.23,3.15,1.25,2.78]
xc=range(5)
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
for x,y in zip(xc,a):
    plt.text(x, y, '%.2f' % y, ha='right', va= 'bottom')
for x,y in zip(xc,b):
    plt.text(x, y, '%.2f' % y, ha='left', va= 'top')
plt.plot(xc,a)
plt.plot(xc,b)
plt.xlabel('num of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.title('train_loss vs val_loss')
plt.legend(['train','val'])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

You can give colors with `color` attribute:

```
for x,y in zip(xc,a):
    plt.text(x, y, '%.2f' % y, ha='right', va= 'bottom', color='blue')
for x,y in zip(xc,b):
    plt.text(x, y, '%.2f' % y, ha='left', va= 'top', color='orange')
```

Comment: plz help to change the color of font of values also. may be blue and orange

Comment: @Hitesh Use `plt.text(x, y, '%.2f' % y, ha='right', va= 'bottom', color='blue')`

Comment: @Hitesh you can give any color name in the `color` attribute. See the edit.

Comment: @Hitesh glad to help.

Comment: how take values inside like 2.78 and 1.23 in above graph who is going outside the graph, without increasing figsize